# Apache CXF: jax-rs Client - GET Array of Objects

Tags: java, rest, collections, cxf, jax-rs

I want to get an Array of Objects via GET from my service.

So I tried:

```
 reader.setEntityClass(ObjectDTO[].class); 
 res = client.get();    
 List<ObjectDTO> objects = (List<ObjectDTO>) res.getEntity();
```

Error:

```
 Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Service:

```
    @GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<ObjectDTO> getObjects();
```

My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
        org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: .Problem with reading the response message, class : class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, ContentType : application/xml.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportMessageHandlerProblem(AbstractClient.java:614)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:452)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:782)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:766)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:696)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:268)
        at com.bachelor.cxf.CxfClientTest.getEstatesWebClient(CxfClientTest.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
        Caused by: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: No reader for Response entity java.util.List
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ResponseReader.readFrom(ResponseReader.java:92)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ResponseReader.readFrom(ResponseReader.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ResponseReader.readFrom(ResponseReader.java:40)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:450)
        ... 30 more
```

EDIT:

I tried another approach as well:

```
 List<ObjectDTO> objects = (List<ObjectDTO>) client.get(ObjectDTO.class);
```

and I get:

```
    1435 [main] WARN org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider - javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
    - with linked exception:
    [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"objectDTOes"). Expected elements are <{}objectDTO>]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:332)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.unmarshalFromInputStream(JAXBElementProvider.java:258)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.doUnmarshal(JAXBElementProvider.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.readFrom(JAXBElementProvider.java:182)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:450)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:782)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:766)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:696)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:324)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:435)
        at com.bachelor.cxf.CxfClientTest.getEstatesWebClient(CxfClientTest.java:314)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"objectDTOes"). Expected elements are <{}objectDTO>
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1049)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:242)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:176)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"objectDTOes"). Expected elements are <{}objectDTO>
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yay, I didnt noticed the getCollection Method. Now it is just:

```
 (List<ObjectDTO>) client.getCollection(ObjectDTO.class);
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
reader.setEntityClass(Object[].class);
```

to:

```
reader.setEntityClass(java.util.List.class);
```

Comment: ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient - .Problem with reading the response message, class : class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, ContentType : application/xml.

Comment: can you post the entire stacktrace? (edit the question, don't post it in the comments)

Comment: What CXF version are you using?